# get all rows matching for same value in 2 different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, `members` and `chat`.

I want to get all member ids which had chat with $user_id, here we assume $user_id = '5'

`chat` table is like:

```
id     from    to     message
1      32      12     test
2      25      18     new message
3      5       86     another message
4      53      5      final message
```

`members` table:

```
id user_id
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
```

...

So for the above table contents, my quesry should return `53` and `86` because only these user ids had chat with '5'

my query is:

```
$q = "
SELECT members.user_id
FROM members
LEFT JOIN chat ON chat.to = '5' OR chat.from = '5'
"
```

Expected output is :

```
user_id
86
53
```

But it's not working, how could I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: post member table script :)

Comment: where are the members table fields ?

Comment: Rename columns `from` and `to` because they are **[reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)**.

Comment: if the `members` table has always id=user_id, You may consider to have only one row and drop the second one

Comment: @AycanYaşıt thanks for reminding about the keyword

Comment: I reword your question title to match it more closely to what you really needed, next person who will search for this will find it easier ;)

Comment: edit is approved, but in your query how I could add other columns to get? for example I want to also get `CONTACT(member.name, ' ', member.lastname) AS username`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join clause has to contains one field from members and one field from chat. But you may prefer that way to write your query :

```
$q = "
SELECT CASE chat.to WHEN 5 THEN chat.from ELSE chat.to END as the_other_guy
FROM chat
WHERE chat.from = 5 OR chat.to = 5";
```

**EDIT:** Next time, please ask what you REALLY need in your question, because we cannot guess what you thing. "display id and username of members who talked to user 5" would have been more clear than your first title, which was "how to join 2 table"

```
$q = "
SELECT CASE chat.to WHEN 5 THEN chat.from ELSE chat.to END as the_other_guy, username
FROM chat, members
WHERE 
  (chat.from = 5 AND members.id=chat.to) 
OR (chat.to = 5 AND members.id=chat.from)";
```

Comment: indeed, I used your query which has a 2nd problem : you're looking for `chat.id` and not `members.id`. I edited

Comment: I want the user ids which had contact with `5`, the new code return a not relevant id

Comment: see, all the user ids which have received a message from `5` or sent a message to `5`, thats what I need

Comment: so what did it return ?

Comment: ohh, I understood, you want the other members id, sorry

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40418/discussion-between-behz4d-and-asenar)

Comment: edit is approved, but in your query how I could add other columns to get? for example I want to also get `CONTACT(member.name, ' ', member.lastname) AS username `

Comment: next time, try to formulate clearly your question ;)

Comment: ok, but for now, this qiery is returning wrong values, it should return only 2 records but it is returning 5 records

Answer (score 2):

I think you 're looking for this one:

```
select chat.to from chat where chat.from=5
union
select chat.from from chat where chat.to=5
```

meaning every user_id that user:5 has chatted with

Comment: +1, this is much simplier than the solution I proposed, + you probably don't need the `join`

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = "
SELECT m.id
FROM members as m
LEFT JOIN chat as c 
  ON c.to = m.user_id OR c.from = m.user_id
WHERE m.user_id = '5'
"
```

Comment: I don't think chat id and member id will match.